# jenkins: clean unused workspaces

Tags: jenkins, workspace

On our jenkins server we have workspace directories whose Jobs no longer exist. This takes up precious disk space.

How can I find out which directories are being used by existing Jobs from the others?

The only way I know it to manually look at the Job name. This is impossible to be done for all directories because we have hundreds of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Find out what's on the disk

#### Find your jenkins home

in *Manage Jenkins* -> *Configure System*,

you can see your *Home Directory* of your jenkins server, say `$JENKINS_HOME`

#### Have a look

ssh in to your jenkins server,

```
du -s $JENKINS_HOME/workspace/* | sort -nrk 1
```

and you should have a list of most disk consuming projects, in decending order.

### Find out what's in use

get a document describing your online jobs from jenkins REST service:

http://your.ci-server.com/api/json?tree=jobs[name]

`your.ci-server.com` would be your jenkins server name.

you will get somthing like

```
{"jobs":[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"}]}
```

All you have to do now is to compare these two lists to find out the wanted jobs.